# Suitable struct type for unmarshal of geojson

Tags: go

I want to unmarshal a geojson string into a suitable struct type.
I have three different geojson strings that I want to unmarshal into the same struct:

```
var jsonBlobPointString = []byte(`{"Type":"Point", "Coordinates":[1.1,2.0]}`)
var jsonBlobLineString = []byte(`{"Type":"LineString", "Coordinates":[[1.1,2.0],[3.0,6.3]]}`)
var jsonBlobPolygonString = []byte(`{"Type":"Polygon", "Coordinates":[[[1.1,2.0],[3.0,6.3],[5.1,7.0],[1.1,2.0]]]}`)
```

I came up with a struct type that I´m not totally happy with:

```
type GeojsonType struct {
    Type string
    Coordinates interface{}
}
```

See this link for complete example:
http://play.golang.org/p/Bt-51BX__A

I would rather not use interface{} for Coordinates. 
I would instead use somehting that give me some validation for example Coordinates [] float64 for Point
and Coordinates[][] float64 for LineString.

Is it possible to create a struct type so that Point, LineString and Polygon all can be represented in Coordinates without using interface?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the Unmarshaler interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is to create 3 different types of object from the same json dictionary.

As far as I know that isn't possible, however you can use the [RawMessage](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) type to delay the json decoding and use a bit of pre-processing [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/g6AmR3y4E9)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    Coordinates []float64
}

type Line struct {
    Points [][]float64
}

type Polygon struct {
    Lines [][][]float64
}

type GeojsonType struct {
    Type        string
    Coordinates json.RawMessage
    Point       Point
    Line        Line
    Polygon     Polygon
}

var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
{"Type":"Point", "Coordinates":[1.1,2.0]},
{"Type":"LineString", "Coordinates":[[1.1,2.0],[3.0,6.3]]},
{"Type":"Polygon", "Coordinates":[[[1.1,2.0],[3.0,6.3],[5.1,7.0],[1.1,2.0]]]}
]`)

func main() {
    var geojsonPoints []GeojsonType
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &geojsonPoints)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    // Postprocess the coordinates  

    for i := range geojsonPoints {
        t := &geojsonPoints[i]

        switch t.Type {
        case "Point":
            err = json.Unmarshal(t.Coordinates, &t.Point.Coordinates)
        case "LineString":
            err = json.Unmarshal(t.Coordinates, &t.Line.Points)
        case "Polygon":
            err = json.Unmarshal(t.Coordinates, &t.Polygon.Lines)
        default:
            panic("Unknown type")
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to convert %s: %s", t.Type, err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t)
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
&{Type:Point Coordinates:[91 49 46 49 44 50 46 48 93] Point:{Coordinates:[1.1 2]} Line:{Points:[]} Polygon:{Lines:[]}}
&{Type:LineString Coordinates:[91 91 49 46 49 44 50 46 48 93 44 91 51 46 48 44 54 46 51 93 93] Point:{Coordinates:[]} Line:{Points:[[1.1 2] [3 6.3]]} Polygon:{Lines:[]}}
&{Type:Polygon Coordinates:[91 91 91 49 46 49 44 50 46 48 93 44 91 51 46 48 44 54 46 51 93 44 91 53 46 49 44 55 46 48 93 44 91 49 46 49 44 50 46 48 93 93 93] Point:{Coordinates:[]} Line:{Points:[]} Polygon:{Lines:[[[1.1 2] [3 6.3] [5.1 7] [1.1 2]]]}}
```

Comment: how could you serialise this object back to a geojson?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Nick Craig-Wood answer I built the following Marshal/UnMarshal functions

```
package geojson

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719532/suitable-struct-type-for-unmarshal-of-geojson

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type Point struct {
    Coordinates []float64
}

type Line struct {
    Points [][]float64
}

type Polygon struct {
    Lines [][][]float64
}

type Geojson struct {
    Type        string          `json:"type"`
    Coordinates json.RawMessage `json:"coordinates"`
    Point       Point           `json:"-"`
    Line        Line            `json:"-"`
    Polygon     Polygon         `json:"-"`
}

func (g *Geojson) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {

    type Alias Geojson
    aux := (*Alias)(g)

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &aux)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch g.Type {
    case "Point":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.Point.Coordinates)
    case "LineString":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.Line.Points)
    case "Polygon":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.Polygon.Lines)
    }

    g.Coordinates = []byte(nil)

    return err
}

func (g Geojson) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {

    var raw json.RawMessage
    var err error

    switch g.Type {
    case "Point":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.Point.Coordinates)
    case "LineString":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.Line.Points)
    case "Polygon":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.Polygon.Lines)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    g.Coordinates = raw

    type Alias Geojson
    aux := (*Alias)(&g)
    return json.Marshal(aux)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Madu Alikor answer, completed it for my use case.

```
package geojson

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type PointCoordinates []float64              // Point
type LineCoordinates [][]float64             // 1. Multipoint, 2. LineString
type PolygonCoordinates [][][]float64        // 1. MultiLineString, 2. Polygon
type MultiPolygonCoordinates [][][][]float64 // 1. Multi Polygon

type Point struct {
    PointCoords PointCoordinates
}

type MultiPoint struct {
    MultiPointCoords LineCoordinates
}

type Line struct {
    LineCoords LineCoordinates
}

type MultiLine struct {
    MultiLineCoords PolygonCoordinates
}

type Polygon struct {
    PolygonCoords PolygonCoordinates
}

type MultiPolygon struct {
    MultiPolygonCoords MultiPolygonCoordinates
}

type Geojson struct {
    Type         string          `json:"type"`
    Coordinates  json.RawMessage `json:"coordinates"`
    Point        Point           `json:"-"`
    MultiPoint   MultiPoint      `json:"-"`
    Line         Line            `json:"-"`
    MultiLine    MultiLine       `json:"-"`
    Polygon      Polygon         `json:"-"`
    MultiPolygon MultiPolygon    `json:"-"`
}

func (g *Geojson) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {

    type Alias Geojson
    aux := (*Alias)(g)

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &aux)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch g.Type {
    case "Point":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.Point.PointCoords)
    case "MultiPoint":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.MultiPoint.MultiPointCoords)
    case "LineString":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.Line.LineCoords)
    case "MultiLineString":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.MultiLine.MultiLineCoords)
    case "Polygon":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.Polygon.PolygonCoords)
    case "MultiPolygon":
        err = json.Unmarshal(g.Coordinates, &g.MultiPolygon.MultiPolygonCoords)
    }

    g.Coordinates = []byte(nil)

    return err
}

func (g Geojson) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {

    var raw json.RawMessage
    var err error

    switch g.Type {
    case "Point":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.Point.PointCoords)
    case "MultiPoint":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.MultiPoint.MultiPointCoords)
    case "LineString":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.Line.LineCoords)
    case "MultiLineString":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.MultiLine.MultiLineCoords)
    case "Polygon":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.Polygon.PolygonCoords)
    case "MultiPolygon":
        raw, err = json.Marshal(&g.MultiPolygon.MultiPolygonCoords)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    g.Coordinates = raw

    type Alias Geojson
    aux := (*Alias)(&g)
    return json.Marshal(aux)
}
```